# Issue pulling in maven artifacts from Ivy.xml (generated from SBT) using Gradle

Tags: java, scala, maven, gradle, ivy

I've been attempting to utilize an artifact (and its dependencies) generated from sbt and stored in a local ivy repo accessed by my gradle build.  Here's my build.gradle.

```
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    ivy {
        url "file://${System.getenv('HOME')}/.ivy2/local"
        patternLayout {
            artifact '[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[module](-[classifier]).[ext]'
            ivy '[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivys/ivy.xml'
           }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation     'junit:junit:4.13'

    implementation ('org.testorg:client-lib_2.12:0.12.0-1') {
        targetConfiguration = "compile"
    }
}
```

The top level artifact that I'm looking to use was built with scala 2.12 and ivy correctly adds that to the appropriate artifacts for me except the ones pulled from maven.  Here is one of the dependencies in the client_lib ivy.xml file it's trying to resolve:

```
 <dependency org="io.lemonlabs" name="scala-uri_2.12" rev="1.5.1" conf="compile->default(compile)">
      <artifact name="scala-uri" type="src" ext="jar" conf="*" e:classifier="sources"/>
    </dependency>
```

When I build I get the following error:

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find scala-uri-1.5.1-sources.jar (io.lemonlabs:scala-uri_2.12:1.5.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/lemonlabs/scala-uri_2.12/1.5.1/scala-uri-1.5.1-sources.jar
```

In going to repo.maven.apache.org, I can clearly see the file there with the scala version correctly added to the jar file:

```
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/lemonlabs/scala-uri_2.12/1.5.1/scala-uri_2.12-1.5.1-sources.jar
```

So why isn't gradle (or the ivy plugin) appending the scala version to the filename when it tries to pull it from maven?  If I modify the dependency in the ivy.xml file to:

```
 <dependency org="io.lemonlabs" name="scala-uri_2.12" rev="1.5.1" conf="compile>default(compile)">
      <artifact name="scala-uri_2.12" type="src" ext="jar" conf="*" e:classifier="sources"/>
    </dependency>
```

It works, but this is not an acceptable solution as I have no control over the generation of this library.  I'm sure I'm missing something in my build.gradle file but I've been unable to locate what that is.  Note: other dependencies in the ivy.xml that point to local libs all correctly append the scala version number when resolving, just not the external maven ones.

Perhaps an ivy expert can chime in on whether the ivy.xml file is malformed and the artifact name for external maven dependencies should have the scala version hardcoded in it?

Comment: Which Gradle version do you have in use? Could this be an error in Gradle how it generates the ivy.xml files?

Comment: Could this be helpful? https://discuss.gradle.org/t/ivy-artifactpattern-vs-group-name-version/5949/2

Comment: @kladderradatsch  I'm using gradle 7.0.  Gradle doesn't create the ivy.xml file.  That is done from an external project using sbt.  I'm just importing that library (and its dependencies) into my new application using gradle.

Comment: When the tool scala-sbt.org is the cause of producing malformed ivy.xml files regarding to the artifact name in it you should refine your question above in terms of scala-sbt.org as the cause of failure.

Comment: @kladderradatsch Thanks, but it was not clear to me that the ivy.xml file was malformed as other local artifacts defined in the file which do not contain the scala version are resolved correctly.  It was my understanding that this should be the case with the external dependencies as well, including those from maven.  I'm by no means an ivy expert so I was working from the assumption it was correct and the problem was on the gradle side.  I will update the question in the event that is not the case.

Comment: "... it was not clear to me that the ivy.xml file was malformed as other local artifacts defined in the file which do not contain the scala version are resolved correctly. ..." Yes, because the artifactId (notion in Maven) "scala-uri_2.12" is uncommon because it contains already a version in it and scala-sbt.org seems to be confused by this.